# Python request with authentication (access_token)

Tags: python, authentication, curl, access-token

I am trying to use an API query in Python. From the command line I can use `curl` like so:

```
curl --header "Authorization:access_token myToken" https://website.example/id
```

This gives some JSON output. `myToken` is a hexadecimal variable that remains constant throughout.

I would like to make this call from python so that I can loop through different ids and analyze the output. Before authentication was needed I had done that with `urllib2`. I have also taken a look at the `requests` module but couldn't figure out how to authenticate with it.

Comment: Setting an auth token for the entire session: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47043335/911945

Answer (score 193, accepted):

The [requests](https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master) package has a very nice API for HTTP requests, adding a custom header works like this ([source: official docs](https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers)):

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get(
... 'https://website.example/id', headers={'Authorization': 'access_token myToken'})
```

If you don't want to use an external dependency, the same thing using urllib2 of the standard library looks like this ([source: the missing manual](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml#headers)):

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen(
... urllib2.Request('https://website.example/id', headers={'Authorization': 'access_token myToken'})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried both implementations and I get an HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized.  However, the command line works just fine. I've never worked with access tokens, so just to be clear: the token that I have is 40 digits of the form 3f4264ff etc.

Comment: Strange. What bugs me a little is the colon in the header... ah! Maybe I (or we both ;) just read that wrong. The header might be named "Authorization" and its **value** then would be "access_token long_hexadecimal_string". Want to give that a spin?

Comment: that worked! thank you so much.  what i ended up typing is

    url = 'https://website.com/id'
    head = {'Authorization': 'access_token hex_string'}
    res=requests.get(url, headers=head)

Comment: This solution is deprecated or otherwise not working in default Anaconda install.

Comment: i've one another problem around this. I have a .py file in my code that uses requests get/put/post/delete with authToken generated by a specific POST API. this file is called in an all-time-running service's execution. So wanted to know how to refresh the token whenever a request api call gets Unauthorized error. Is there any provision with requests library to add hooks? Or i need to use some python code to refresh the token.

Comment: What is access_token myToken? From where and how can  I get it? @wosc

Comment: It is an authentication token that the server uses to verify you are authorized to have access to the API. You need to obtain client credentials (username, password, API key) for the API you want to access and then send them (for example, via a get request) to the authentication server. The server returns a string that could be JSON-encoded to your client and you then use that as a token in your API calls. Search for JWT or OAuth to do some more reading and view some examples.

Comment: As @Sowmiya Ragu pointed below, sometimes it's not 'access_token' but 'Bearer'. `response = requests.get(
 'https://website.com/id', headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer myToken'})` . Not sure if this is a version or specific sever's config isuue.

Comment: `myToken = 'aoisjd0910293jijaosjd09j092j091j0asdpo'`  
`response = requests.get( 'https://website.com/id', headers={'Authorization': 'Token myToken'})`

Answer (score 45):

I had the same problem when trying to use a token with Github.

The only syntax that has worked for me with Python 3 is:

```
import requests

myToken = '<token>'
myUrl = '<website>'
head = {'Authorization': 'token {}'.format(myToken)}
response = requests.get(myUrl, headers=head)
```

Comment: What would be the token here? Or how to get authentication token?

Answer (score 26):

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get('https://website.com/id', headers={'Authorization': 'access_token myToken'})
```

If the above doesnt work , try this:

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get('https://api.buildkite.com/v2/organizations/orgName/pipelines/pipelineName/builds/1230', headers={ 'Authorization': 'Bearer <your_token>' })
>>> print response.json()
```

Comment: I had the same issue this week and what ended up working for me was the Authorization bearer option. Not sure why there's a difference, but thanks for providing that option for me to try and successfully get working!

Comment: @SowmiyaRagu the second part works for me `Bearer <my_token>` while the first doesn't because the response is as if the request is not authenticated.

Comment: JULY 2022 : OPTION 2 WORKS ON PYTHON REQUESTS = 2.28.1

Comment: access_token does not work because it is deprecated in python3

Answer (score 12):

```
import requests

BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/v3/getPlan'
token = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImR"

headers = {'Authorization': "Bearer {}".format(token)}
auth_response = requests.get(BASE_URL, headers=headers)

print(auth_response.json())
```

> Output :

```
{
"plans": [
    {
        "field": false,
        "description": "plan 12",
        "enabled": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 12):

A lot of good answers already, but I didn't see this option yet:

If you're using `requests`, you could also specify a [custom authentication](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#custom-authentication) class, similar to `HTTPBasicAuth`. For example:

```py
from requests.auth import AuthBase


class TokenAuth(AuthBase):
    def __init__(self, token, auth_scheme='Bearer'):
        self.token = token
        self.auth_scheme = auth_scheme

    def __call__(self, request):
        request.headers['Authorization'] = f'{self.auth_scheme} {self.token}'
        return request
```

This could be used as follows (using the custom [auth_scheme](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) from the example):

```py
response = requests.get(
    url='https://example.com', 
    auth=TokenAuth(token='abcde', auth_scheme='access_token'),
)
```

This may look like a more complicated way to set the `Request.headers` attribute, but it can be advantageous if you want to support multiple types of authentication. Note this allows us to use the `auth` argument instead of the `headers` argument.

Comment: Useful because you don't have to merge headers manually

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried the `uncurl` package (https://github.com/spulec/uncurl)? You can install it via pip, `pip install uncurl`. Your curl request returns:

```sh
>>> uncurl "curl --header \"Authorization:access_token myToken\" https://website.com/id"

requests.get("https://website.com/id",
    headers={
        "Authorization": "access_token myToken"
    },
    cookies={},
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'll add a bit hint: it seems what you pass as the key value of a header depends on your authorization type, in my case that was `PRIVATE-TOKEN`

```py
header = {'PRIVATE-TOKEN': 'my_token'}
response = requests.get(myUrl, headers=header)
```

Answer (score 3):

One of the option used in python to retrieve below:

```py
import requests

token="abcd" < retrieved based>
headers = {'Authorization': "Bearer {}".format(token)}
response = requests.get(
    'https://<url api>',
    headers=headers,
    verify="root ca certificate"
)

print(response.content)
```

If you get hostname mismatch error then additional SANs need to be configured in the server with the hostnames.

Hope this helps.