# Python requests library how to pass Authorization header with single token

Tags: python, get, authorization, token, python-requests

I have a request URI and a token. If I use:

```
curl -s "<MY_URI>" -H "Authorization: TOK:<MY_TOKEN>"
```

etc., I get a 200 and view the corresponding JSON data.
So, I installed requests and when I attempt to access this resource I get a 403 probably because I do not know the correct syntax to pass that token. Can anyone help me figure it out?
This is what I have:

```
import sys,socket
import requests

r = requests.get('<MY_URI>','<MY_TOKEN>')
r. status_code
```

I already tried:

```
r = requests.get('<MY_URI>',auth=('<MY_TOKEN>'))
r = requests.get('<MY_URI>',auth=('TOK','<MY_TOKEN>'))
r = requests.get('<MY_URI>',headers=('Authorization: TOK:<MY_TOKEN>'))
```

But none of these work.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

In python:

```
('<MY_TOKEN>')
```

is equivalent to

```
'<MY_TOKEN>'
```

And requests interprets

```
('TOK', '<MY_TOKEN>')
```

As you wanting requests to use Basic Authentication and craft an authorization header like so:

```
'VE9LOjxNWV9UT0tFTj4K'
```

Which is the base64 representation of `'TOK:<MY_TOKEN>'`

To pass your own header you pass in a dictionary like so:

```
r = requests.get('<MY_URI>', headers={'Authorization': 'TOK:<MY_TOKEN>'})
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 323, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)

Comment: @rebHelium can you [gist](https://gist.github.com) that? That is not the whole stack trace and there's no indication of what you actually tried.

Comment: Sorry, Stack Overflow did not allow me to post the whole output. I did exactly as you suggested: r = requests.get('whatever url i have', headers={'Authorization': 'TOK:whatever token i have'})

Comment: No need to apologize. Did it work? You accepted my answer but it seems to have caused an exception for you. If you create a [gist](https://gist.github.com) I can help you with greater ease than having a conversation here.

Comment: Sigma, I actually missed one small detail on your code that caused the error. The actual code is confidential so I cannot gist. But I will post additional questions since I want to improve my Python skills, if you want to look. They are very simple questions I am sure you would know.

Comment: Thanks. Here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150208/python-search-regex-from-variable-inside-a-list   I haven't been able to use regex and get what I need. I will re-edit the question.

Comment: I was able to get it to work using:

> r = requests.get('<MY_URI>', headers={'Authorization': 'MY_TOKEN_HERE'})

Comment: This works! Make sure the spelling of Authorization is right. I used it as Authorisation and the request failed.

Answer (score 63):

I was looking for something similar and came across [this](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/authentication/). It looks like in the first option you mentioned

```py
r = requests.get('<MY_URI>', auth=('<MY_TOKEN>'))
```

"auth" takes two parameters: username and password, so the actual statement should be

```py
r=requests.get('<MY_URI>', auth=('<YOUR_USERNAME>', '<YOUR_PASSWORD>'))
```

In my case, there was no password, so I left the second parameter in auth field empty as shown below:

```py
r=requests.get('<MY_URI', auth=('MY_USERNAME', ''))
```

Hope this helps somebody :)

Comment: if you try `r = requests.get('<MY_URI>',auth=('<MY_TOKEN>'))`, you will get `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`. that stumped me for a while until i came across this :/

Comment: Your anserd helped me but only after readin the link you provide which you came accros. Working with the HTTPBasicAuth import from requests.auth makes it very easy!

Answer (score 55):

This worked for me:

```
access_token = #yourAccessTokenHere#

result = requests.post(url,
      headers={'Content-Type':'application/json',
               'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(access_token)})
```

Answer (score 28):

You can also set headers for the entire session:

```
TOKEN = 'abcd0123'
HEADERS = {'Authorization': 'token {}'.format(TOKEN)}

with requests.Session() as s:

    s.headers.update(HEADERS)
    resp = s.get('http://example.com/')
```

Answer (score 9):

I found it here, it's working for me with Linkedin:
https://auth0.com/docs/flows/guides/auth-code/call-api-auth-code
The code I used with Linkedin login is:

```
ref = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me'
headers = {"content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",'Authorization':'Bearer {}'.format(access_token)}
Linkedin_user_info = requests.get(ref1, headers=headers).json()
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try something like this

```
r = requests.get(ENDPOINT, params=params, headers={'Authorization': 'Basic %s' %  API_KEY})
```

Answer (score 5):

Requests natively supports basic auth only with user-pass params, not with tokens.

You could, if you wanted, add the following class to have requests support token based basic authentication:

```
import requests
from base64 import b64encode

class BasicAuthToken(requests.auth.AuthBase):
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.token = token
    def __call__(self, r):
        authstr = 'Basic ' + b64encode(('token:' + self.token).encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
        r.headers['Authorization'] = authstr
        return r
```

Then, to use it run the following request :

```
r = requests.get(url, auth=BasicAuthToken(api_token))
```

An alternative would be to formulate a custom header instead, just as was suggested by other users here.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/ray/musics/', headers={'Authorization': 'Token 22ec0cc4207ebead1f51dea06ff149342082b190'})
```

My code uses user generated token.

Answer (score 2):

You have a request needing an authorization maybe you have a result `401`.

Suppose your request is like this :

```
REQ ='https://api.asite.com/something/else/else'
```

You have your token :

```
TOKEN = 'fliuzabuvdgfnsuczkncsq12454632'
```

build your header like this :

```
HEADER = {'Authorization': f'{TOKEN}'}
```

and use it like this :

```
req.get(REQ, headers=HEADER)
```

display your result like this :

```
req.get(COACH, headers=HEADER).json()
```