# Python search regex from variable inside a list

Tags: python, regex, list, variables, search

I have:

```
data = [[u'text'],[u'element'],[u'text00']]
pattern = text
pattern2 = EL
pattern3 = 00
```

Using regex I want to search and return:

```
text, text00 # for pattern
element      # for pattern2
text00       # for pattern3
```

Comment: What are you expecting?

Comment: To find the pattern. If user enters "red" and the list is ["red", "lightred", "orange red", "blue"] then it should return true.

Comment: That's what `if pattern in data:` already returns

Comment: @Haidro I think OP wants "red", "lightred", "orange red" to be returned for `red`.

Comment: @SantoshKumar hm, thought so. Just odd how the example structure already has `red` in it

Comment: It doesn't work if the pattern is not exactly the same as entered. So if I enter "tred" even though it is in "lightred" it will return false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
data = [[u'text'], [u'element'], [u'text00']]
patterns = [u'text', u'EL', u'00']
results = []
for pattern in patterns:
    results.append([x[0] for x in data if re.search(pattern, x[0], flags=re.I)])
print  results
```

or, more concisely:

```
import re
data = [[u'text'], [u'element'], [u'text00']]
patterns = [u'text', u'EL', u'00']
results = [[x[0] for x in data if re.search(pattern, x[0], flags=re.I)] for pattern in patterns]
print  results
```

Comment: Yes, that did it, tks!

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
>>> L = ["red", "lightred", "orange red", "blue"]
>>> keyword = 'red'
>>> import re
>>> any(re.search(keyword, i) is not None for i in L)
True
```

Comment: OK, this is useful butI get: TypeError: expected string or buffer. Please note that L will be a list like this: [[[u'red']], [u'blue'], [[u'lightred']]] and keyword is user input

Comment: @rebHelium That's a very odd list. Using the code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python/2158532#2158532), flatten the list, then use my code