# Searching for a word within a list of lists

Tags: sublist

I'm trying to write a function that will search a list of lists to find a word or fragment given by the user and return all units including that word.

here's what I have so far:

```
def cat(dogs):
"""
 searches for cat names in dogs
"""
  search = raw_input("search for: ")
  word = search[0].upper() + search[1:]

  for i in range(len(dogs)):
    if word in dogs[i]: 
      print "yes"
    else:
     print "sorry, nothing found"
     return
```

how do I fix this?

Thanks so much!!

Comment: I assume that the `if .. else` blocks are in the `for` loop. Try printing the value of `i`.

Comment: yes they are - my bad. and still, nothing except "sorry, nothing found".

Comment: Try [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19174399/666823)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you should convert your both string and the strings in `stockdata` to uppercase in the search process so it'd be able to detect both `Computer` and `computer`

You should also print `sorry, not found` if no result was found and I've added a `results` variable to see the search results.

```
def company(stockdata):
    """
     searches for companies with the word inputted and gives back full
     company names and ticker tags
     """
    found = False
    results = []
    search = raw_input("search for: ")
    word = search.upper()

    for i in range(len(stockdata)):
        if word in stockdata[i][0].upper() or word in stockdata[i][1].upper(): # I've used stockdata[i][0] because the string is in a list of list
            found = True
            results.append(stockdata[i][0])
    if found:
        print 'yes'
        print 'results : ',results
    else:
        print "sorry, nothing found"

stock  = [['AAME', 'Atlantic American Corporation', '2013-11-04', 4.04, 4.05, 4.01, 4.05, 5400.0, 4.05], ['AAON', 'AAON Inc.', '2013-11-04', 27.28, 27.48, 27.08, 27.32, 96300.0, 27.32], ['AAPL', 'Apple Inc.', '2013-11-04', 521.1, 526.82, 518.81, 526.75, 8716100.0, 526.75], ['AAWW', 'Atlas Air Worldwide Holdings', '2013-11-04', 38.65, 39.48, 38.65, 38.93, 490500.0, 38.93], ['AAXJ', 'iShares MSCI All Country Asia ex Japan Index Fund', '2013-11-04', 60.55, 60.55, 60.3, 60.48, 260300.0, 60.48], ['ABAX', 'ABAXIS Inc.', '2013-11-04', 36.01, 36.91, 35.89, 36.2, 208300.0, 36.2]]
company(stock)
```

**produces:** *for the search term* **abaxis**

```
yes
results :  ['ABAX']
```

*Note: please provide a sample of your stock data list which is passed onto the function if possible as to ensure this works*

Comment: still doesn't work - here's a sample of my data list.

Comment: [['AAME', 'Atlantic American Corporation', '2013-11-04', 4.04, 4.05, 4.01, 4.05, 5400.0, 4.05], ['AAON', 'AAON  Inc.', '2013-11-04', 27.28, 27.48, 27.08, 27.32, 96300.0, 27.32], ['AAPL', 'Apple Inc.', '2013-11-04', 521.1, 526.82, 518.81, 526.75, 8716100.0, 526.75], ['AAWW', 'Atlas Air Worldwide Holdings', '2013-11-04', 38.65, 39.48, 38.65, 38.93, 490500.0, 38.93], ['AAXJ', 'iShares MSCI All Country Asia ex Japan Index Fund', '2013-11-04', 60.55, 60.55, 60.3, 60.48, 260300.0, 60.48], ['ABAX', 'ABAXIS  Inc.', '2013-11-04', 36.01, 36.91, 35.89, 36.2, 208300.0, 36.2]]

Answer (score 0):

```
'''
 searches for companies with the word input and gives back full
 company names and ticker tags  
'''
def company(stockdata):
    searchString = raw_input("search for: ")
    flatList = [item.upper() for sublist in stockdata for item in sublist]
    if any(searchString.upper() in s for s in flatList):
        print "Yes"
    else:
        print "sorry, nothing found"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're searching a list of lists, you need another `for` loop unless I'm misunderstanding your question. K DawG has given the best answer so far. Unfortunately I can't upvote it.

```
def company(stockdata):
    search = raw_input("search for: ")
    word = search.upper()

    for i in range(len(stockdata)):
        for j in range(len(stockdata[i])):
            if word in stockdata[i][j].upper(): 
                print stockdata[i][j]
            else:
                print "sorry, nothing found"
    return

data = [["computer", "cheese"], ["apple"], ["mac Computers"]]

company(data)
```

returns:

```
computer
sorry, nothing found
sorry, nothing found
mac Computers
```