# Python list comprehension nested loop

Tags: python, arrays, list, list-comprehension

Right now I'm "removing" emails from a list by mapping a new list excluding the things I don't want.   This looked like:

```
    pattern = re.compile('b\.com')

    emails = ['user@a.com', 'user@b.com', 'user@c.com', 'user@d.com']
    emails = [e for e in emails if pattern.search(e) == None]
    # resulting list:  ['user@a.com', 'user@c.com']
```

However, now I need to filter out multiple domains, so I have a list of domains that need to be filtered out.

```
    pattern_list = ['b.com', 'c.com']
```

Is there a way to do this still in list comprehension form or am I going to have to revert back to nested for loops?

Note: splitting the string at the @ and doing `word[1] in pattern_list` won't work because `c.com` needs to catch `sub.c.com` as well.

Comment: I dont like list comprehension is the best way to address this - You might be able to do it, but a lot cumbersome. Look at this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150208/python-search-regex-from-variable-inside-a-list

Comment: Note that your existing example will also exclude, for instance `user@crumb.com` and `bob.com@bob.com`.  Is that what you want?

Comment: When you're making list comprehensions of list comprehensions, it's often better to use generators (change the square brackets to parens), which are more memory efficient and chain together nicely.

Comment: Also, in your regex `.` is a special character, so it will also exclude `bob@bocom`, since `b.com` matches `bocom`.  Is that also what you want?

Comment: @BrenBarn That's a good point, although in my actual code the domains are rather long and unique and I do want to move anything containing them.

Comment: Using `is None` reads better than `== None`. Also it's a bit more efficient since `is` cannot be overloaded and the interpreter can just do a pointer comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, even without using a regex.  One is:

```
[e for e in emails if not any(pat in e for pat in pattern_list)]
```

This will also exclude emails like `user@crumb.com` and `bob.com@bob.com`, but so does your original solution.  It does not, however, exclude cases like `user@bocom`, which your existing solution does.  Again, it's not clear if your existing solution actually does what you think it does.

Another possibility is to combine your patterns into one with `rx = '|'.join(pattern_list)` and then match on that regex.  Again, though, you'll need to use a more complex regex if you want to only match `b.com` as a full domain (not as just part of the domain or as part of the username).

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('b.com$|c.com$')

emails = ['user@a.com', 'user@b.com', 'user@c.com', 'user@d.com']

emails = [e for e in emails if pattern.search(e) == None]

print emails
```

what about this