# Why am I receiving a code that I am not authorized (401) when I am giving my access token?

Tags: python, rest, python-requests, surveymonkey

Why is it that I receive a 401 Error when I attempt to get info from the HOST here?

I'm using my token, shouldn't that give me full access?

```
   HOST = "https://api.surveymonkey.com/v3/surveys"


   r= requests.get(HOST, api_token)
   r.text
   print r
```

Answer (score 2):

You pass api_token in a wrong way. Read the website document to see how do they pass token is the right way to solve your question.

In ordinary situations we will do something like this:

```
requests.get(HOST, auth=(user,api_token))
```

But sometime we can pass token into headers straightly:

```
requests.get(HOST, headers={'Authorization': "Bearer {}".format(api_token)})
requests.get(HOST, headers={'Authorization': api_token})
```

Read [Python requests library how to pass Authorization header with single token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19069701/python-requests-library-how-to-pass-authorization-header-with-single-token) to know more about how to pass token straightly.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/?python#surveys

Python example is on the right.