# Setting Token Header in Python Requests

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am calling my REST services with the following command using curl

```
export TOKEN= '<random>'
curl -X "GET" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization:Bearer ${TOKEN}" http://my-server.com
```

I am trying to map the same code using requests library of Python

```
import requests

url = 'https://httpbin.org/bearer'
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer', 'Content-Type':'application/json'}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)
```

My question is, how can I set my TOKEN value in the code?

Comment: Python has string interpolation just like your shell does. `f'Bearer {token}"` for example, puts the value of the variable `token` into the string value for the header `Authorization`.

Comment: Or just use concatenation, so `'Bearer ' + token`. None of this is specific to Python requests, this is *just* string manipulation.

Comment: Are you (at least in part) asking how to get the value of token from the TOKEN environment variable in Python?

Comment: Oh so using just 'Authorization': 'Bearer' + <token> would do the trick?

Comment: Yeah..thanks it worked.  I was trying out {'Authorization': 'Bearer=<TOKEN>'}.  Sorry for this dumb question.  My thinking was totally lost..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python requests library how to pass Authorization header with single token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19069701/python-requests-library-how-to-pass-authorization-header-with-single-token)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authorization token can be added in a dict form to the headers argument as shown below:

```
hed = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth_token,
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url=url, headers=hed)
```

I suggest reading up on this https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/

Comment: I thought there was some special handling to this..let me try again.  Thanks.

Comment: Sure, please mark the answer as "Accepted" if it solves your issue

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your current line for this one

`headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token, 'Content-Type':'application/json'}`

Depends now where you get the token from, but to include the token that's the way.