# How to make url request in python with authorization

Tags: python

I am querying an api with postman which requires the following header/auth to set
[image]

How do I set these params programmatically in requests library or some other library

Comment: from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19072991/15020017
requests.get('url', headers={'Authorization': 'token'})

Comment: Check this [link](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python requests library how to pass Authorization header with single token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19069701/python-requests-library-how-to-pass-authorization-header-with-single-token)

Comment: @Dennis @Steve: No this is not working.. I have tried `headers = {'Authorization' :'X-API-KEY:MY_API_KEY'}` but its not working (403 error)

Comment: Maybe the key is not right?@frazman

Comment: @Dennis: I was able to figure this out (answered my own question below :) )

Comment: Nice it worked @frazman

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.. as none of the suggestions mentioned in the comments worked for me.

```
headers = {
  'X-API-KEY': 'API_KEY'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```