# How to read headers from request

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have an API, those who would access this API would have to pass an authorization token, so my question is how can I get that auth token from headers?

```
class RealTimeAPI(APIView):
    def post(request):
        pass
```

Comment: Marking as duplicate...  [Check this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19072991/10856970)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python requests library how to pass Authorization header with single token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19069701/python-requests-library-how-to-pass-authorization-header-with-single-token)

Comment: @MattDMo I have written a heavy api, but can post all here, just need some technical clarification, hence posted a dummy api.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some middleware which will check the headers.[use this reference](https://medium.com/swlh/creating-middlewares-with-python-flask-166bd03f2fd4)
I have implemented these code in Flask, hope it will help for django also.

In check_headers.py   (i.e., middleware of the api)

```
   from flask import Response, request
   def check_header(funcn):
        @wraps(funcn)
        def _inner(*args, **kwargs):
             print(request.headers)
             # your code for checking the api token in the header
             return funcn(*args,**kwargs)

        return _inner
```

In app.py

```
from check_headers  import check_header
...    
@app.route('/dashboard', methods=['POST'])
@check_header
def get_course_recommendation():
    return "dashboard.html"
```