# How to avoid 403 HTTP response

Tags: http, web, curl

I do http request from Python (Linux) and receive 403 response code.
But if I do the same request from Windows Chrome web-browser, the response is succesful (200).
What should I do to get succesfull response from Python? [image]

Comment: 403 is unauthorized.. So your chrome browser has some auth headers set already., You'll need to apply those to your python http client. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19069701/python-requests-library-how-to-pass-authorization-header-with-single-token

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.