# Pyhton requests library passing Authorization header with single token, still getting 403

Tags: python, api, python-requests

Code-

```py
HEADER= {
    'Authorization': f'Token {TOKEN}'
}

resp= requests.request(
    "GET",
    url,
    headers=HEADER
)
```

Error message-

```
{'detail': 'Authentication credentials were not provided.'}
```

resp.request.headers output

```
{'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.28.1', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
```

I have tried passing HEADER dict directly in request function (with/without fstring)
directly used .get
Basically tried everything mentioned here [Python requests library how to pass Authorization header with single token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19069701/python-requests-library-how-to-pass-authorization-header-with-single-token)

nothing worked...any idea what might be wrong
TOKEN is correct

Comment: Can you provide elements so we can reproduce your problem and/or the documentation of the API you want to interact with ?

Comment: sorry for late response, it was an interview assignment...I reported the issue but issue wasn't resolved. Anyway thanks you guys

Answer (score 0):

'Authentication credentials were not provided.' should be 401, and, 403 means you don't have the permission, maybe you should talk to the api provider.