# API access to trading platform using Python

Tags: python, api

I'm new to getting data using API and Python. I want to pull data from my trading platform. They've provided the following instructions:

http://www.questrade.com/api/documentation/getting-started

I'm ok up to step 4 and have an access token. I need help with step 5. How do I translate this request:

```
GET /v1/accounts HTTP/1.1
Host: https://api01.iq.questrade.com
Authorization: Bearer C3lTUKuNQrAAmSD/TPjuV/HI7aNrAwDp
```

into Python code? I've tried

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://api01.iq.questrade.com/v1/accounts', headers={'Authorization': 'access_token myToken'})
```

I tried that after reading this: [python request with authentication (access_token)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825278/python-request-with-authentication-access-token)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer C3lTUKuNQrAAmSD/TPjuV/HI7aNrAwDp'}`

Comment: doesn't seem to work. Getting <Response [401]>

Comment: you should substitute in your real access token for the one after `Bearer ` in the example above. But that is the format of the header that's expected. A `401` error is Unauthorized, which means the token is invalid.

Comment: I did substitute my real access token. I'll check with the trading platform why this is happening...

Comment: step 4 is the "login" functionality, have you exchanged the token you got from the user frontend for the `access_token` object from the response? has it expired in the interim, possibly?

Comment: I did that. I'm using the 'access_token' from the returned json message from Step 4. I don't think it expired since the frontend says it's good for 7 days.

Answer (score 3):

As you point out, after step 4 you should have received an access token as follows:

```
{
    “access_token”: ”C3lTUKuNQrAAmSD/TPjuV/HI7aNrAwDp”,
    “token_type”: ”Bearer”,
    “expires_in”: 300,
    “refresh_token”: ”aSBe7wAAdx88QTbwut0tiu3SYic3ox8F”,
    “api_server”: ”https://api01.iq.questrade.com”
}
```

To make subsequent API calls, you will need to construct your URI as follows:

```
uri = [api_server]/v1/[rest_operation]

e.g.
uri = "https://api01.iq.questrade.com/v1/time"

Note: Make sure you use the same [api_server] that you received in your json object from step 4, otherwise your calls will not work with the given access_token
```

Next, construct your headers as follows:

```
headers = {'Authorization': [token_type] + ' ' + [access_token]}

e.g.
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer C3lTUKuNQrAAmSD/TPjuV/HI7aNrAwDp'}
```

Finally, make your requests call as follows

```
r = requests.get(uri, headers=headers)
response = r.json()
```

Hope this helps!

Note: You can find a Questrade API Python wrapper on GitHub which handles all of the above for you.
https://github.com/pcinat/QuestradeAPI_PythonWrapper

Answer (score 1):

Improving a bit on Peter's reply (Thank you Peter!)
start by using the token you got from the QT website to obtain an access_token and get an api_server assigned to handle your requests.

```
# replace XXXXXXXX with the token given to you in your questrade account

import requests

r = requests.get('https://login.questrade.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=XXXXXXXX')

access_token = str(r.json()['access_token'])
refresh_token= str(r.json()['refresh_token']) # you will need this refresh_token to obtain another access_token when it expires
api_server= str(r.json()['api_server'])
token_type= str(r.json()['token_type'])
api_server= str(r.json()['api_server'])
expires_in = str(r.json()['expires_in'])

# uri = api_server+'v1/'+[action] - let's try checking the server's time:
uri = api_server+'v1/'+'time'
headers = {'Authorization': token_type +' '+access_token}
# will look sth like this
 
#    headers will look sth like    {'Authorization': 'Bearer ix7rAhcXx83judEVUa8egpK2JqhPD2_z0'}
#        uri will look sth like    'https://api05.iq.questrade.com/v1/time'

# you can test now with
r = requests.get(uri, headers=headers)
response = r.json()
print(response)
```