# Accessing Google Shopping API via Python

Tags: python, google-content-api

I am quite new to Google APIs and I have been a bit lost :)

First I played around with the [Google APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/content/v2/) and everything was working fine, all my requests.

Then I starting writing a small Python Script to authorise and call the API through a Service Account.

It looks like this:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

import httplib2
import json
import os


credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    filename='/Users/Shopping Dashboard.json',
    scopes='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/content')

http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

service = build('content', 'v2', http=http)
print service.accounts().authinfo().execute()

request = service.accounts().list(merchantId='xxx', maxResults=50)
result = request.execute()
print result
```

However although I though it was kind of OK I still get this error

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 401 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/content/v2/xxxxx/accounts?alt=json&maxResults=50 returned "User cannot access account xxxxx">
```

I think what I miss here is kind of creating my token (?) before calling the url? But how is this created? I know there are 1000 examples out there, and I used some scripts that are already in github and they work but they are already too sophisticated and complicated for me to understand. What I miss here is to understand how this process works with some simple example and be able to replicate the logic..

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Turns out your "Shopping Dashboard.json" file must come from merchant center itself, as opposed to the google developer console.

- Make sure you have admin access
- In Merchant Center go to the ... drop down menu > Content API
- Click the Authentication tab & Generate API key. You'll only be able to see this tab if you have admin access.
- Save content-api-key.json in place of /Users/Shopping Dashboard.json

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a token thing. When using this type of APIs, a token is always necessary. but check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825278/python-request-with-authentication-access-token) to see how it's done using the urllib2.

Comment: I still don't get it, I am not sure if in the service account this is the case actually. for example in this piece of code there is no token: https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/blob/master/samples/service_account/tasks.py

Comment: I believe the code sample from github is quite clear and the comments are quite informative. But have you tried to run the code without adding parameters to the list method?