# BlueJeans ApiException: 415 "Unsupported Media Type"

Tags: python, api, bluejeans

I'm trying to use the BlueJeans API to create a client application following the example at https://github.com/bluejeans/api-rest-meetings/blob/master/libs/python/docs/ApplicationApi.md#create_client_application. I've obtained a client ID and secret as well as a user ID and saved them in my Django settings. I've also written a function to obtain an access token:

```
import json
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import requests
import logging
import BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi
from django.conf import settings
from rest_framework import status

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class ConferenceScheduler(object):
    BASE_URL = 'https://api.bluejeans.com'

    @staticmethod
    def get_token():
        # Obtain an access token to initiate a session with BlueJeans
        # (We use the Client Grant Type which grants us enterprise-level access)
        response = requests.post(
            url=urljoin(base=ConferenceScheduler.BASE_URL, url='/oauth2/token'),
            json={
                'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
                'client_id': settings.BLUEJEANS_KEY,
                'client_secret': settings.BLUEJEANS_SECRET})
        if response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK:
            return json.loads(response.content).get('access_token')
        else:
            logger.error(f"A request for a BlueJeans access token returned a non-200 response.\n"
                         f"Status code: {response.status_code}\n"
                         f"Reason: {response.reason}")
```

Continuing in the Django shell, I've tried to follow the steps in the example, but I get an `ApiException`:

```
In [1]: from lucy_web.lib.conferencing import *

In [2]: BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi.configuration.api_key['access_token'] = ConferenceSch
   ...: eduler.get_token()

In [3]: api_instance = BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi.ApplicationApi()

In [4]: user_id = settings.BLUEJEANS_USER_ID


In [6]: application = BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi.Application()

In [7]: api_response = api_instance.create_client_application(user_id, application)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ApiException                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-1bf90ba9e2a8> in <module>()
----> 1 api_response = api_instance.create_client_application(user_id, application)

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi/apis/application_api.py in create_client_application(self, user_id, application, **kwargs)
     65             return self.create_client_application_with_http_info(user_id, application, **kwargs)
     66         else:
---> 67             (data) = self.create_client_application_with_http_info(user_id, application, **kwargs)
     68             return data
     69 

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi/apis/application_api.py in create_client_application_with_http_info(self, user_id, application, **kwargs)
    148                                         _preload_content=params.get('_preload_content', True),
    149                                         _request_timeout=params.get('_request_timeout'),
--> 150                                         collection_formats=collection_formats)
    151 
    152     def regenerate_client_application_secret(self, user_id, client_id, **kwargs):

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi/api_client.py in call_api(self, resource_path, method, path_params, query_params, header_params, body, post_params, files, response_type, auth_settings, callback, _return_http_data_only, collection_formats, _preload_content, _request_timeout)
    324                                    body, post_params, files,
    325                                    response_type, auth_settings, callback,
--> 326                                    _return_http_data_only, collection_formats, _preload_content, _request_timeout)
    327         else:
    328             thread = threading.Thread(target=self.__call_api,

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi/api_client.py in __call_api(self, resource_path, method, path_params, query_params, header_params, body, post_params, files, response_type, auth_settings, callback, _return_http_data_only, collection_formats, _preload_content, _request_timeout)
    151                                      post_params=post_params, body=body,
    152                                      _preload_content=_preload_content,
--> 153                                      _request_timeout=_request_timeout)
    154 
    155         self.last_response = response_data

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi/api_client.py in request(self, method, url, query_params, headers, post_params, body, _preload_content, _request_timeout)
    369                                          _preload_content=_preload_content,
    370                                          _request_timeout=_request_timeout,
--> 371                                          body=body)
    372         elif method == "PUT":
    373             return self.rest_client.PUT(url,

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi/rest.py in POST(self, url, headers, query_params, post_params, body, _preload_content, _request_timeout)
    261                             _preload_content=_preload_content,
    262                             _request_timeout=_request_timeout,
--> 263                             body=body)
    264 
    265     def PUT(self, url, headers=None, query_params=None, post_params=None, body=None, _preload_content=True,

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi/rest.py in request(self, method, url, query_params, headers, body, post_params, _preload_content, _request_timeout)
    217 
    218         if not 200 <= r.status <= 299:
--> 219             raise ApiException(http_resp=r)
    220 
    221         return r

ApiException: (415)
Reason: Unsupported Media Type
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Server': 'BlueJeans Proxy', 'Date': 'Fri, 06 Jul 2018 22:17:24 GMT', 'X-NewRelic-App-Data': 'PxQAV1ZaABADUVZbBAACU0YdFGQHBDcQUQxLA1tMXV1dORYyVBNFDgFCa04tBkFoRB0RBwpSWAtKU1pGBwwGA14RFhFdSkJbUABKT10IVQcHT1QNA010WlYBAhtUXVIlC19CUgsIBhAcQlkMVldAU0cMVg8MOl0NClNqPERPCB0ASFFMBwMBU1UCAAZRSlNOEgYLWgAAVwMEXQoAUlUCAVAUag==', 'X-Trace-Token': 'sj1-prod-cobalt-03-158215204', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'Content-Length': '47'})
HTTP response body: {"code":415,"message":"Unsupported Media Type"}
```

I'm nonplussed as to what could be the issue here because the `user_id` is specified as an integer as in the documentation. How can I get a valid response from this endpoint?

**Update**

I've also tried to make an 'ordinary' request with a header containing the access token as described in [python request with authentication (access_token)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825278/python-request-with-authentication-access-token). In this case, however, I get a `401` (Unauthorized) response:

```
In [9]: BASE_URL = ConferenceScheduler.BASE_URL

In [10]: BASE_URL
Out[10]: 'https://api.bluejeans.com'

In [11]: url = urljoin(BASE_URL, f'/v1/user/{settings.BLUEJEANS_USER_ID}')

In [13]: session = requests.Session()

In [14]: token = ConferenceScheduler.get_token()

In [15]: session.headers.update({'Authorization': f'access_token {token}'})

In [16]: response = session.get(url)

In [17]: response.status_code
Out[17]: 401

In [19]: response.reason
Out[19]: 'Unauthorized'
```

My token is still valid, as checked by this API call:

```
In [22]: response = requests.get(urljoin(BASE_URL, '/oauth2/tokenInfo'), params={'access_token': token}
    ...: )

In [23]: response.status_code
Out[23]: 200
```

So an additional question is: how would I make requests using `requests` instead of the `BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BlueJeans API was built using the Swagger code generation project, and I managed to get it to work on the development site (https://bluejeans.github.io/api-rest-meetings/site/index.html) by filling out the fields in the payload (description, name, app logo URL, and redirect URL).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Usually you get the 415 Unsupported Media Type error when you omit the http header: **Content-Type: application/json**

Add this, and that error should go away