# Connecting to a website that does not have API (with requests)

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to connect to the following website with `requests` (in Python) - [link](https://www.tapuz.co.il/Common/SignInPage.aspx?backUrl=http://www.tapuz.co.il/Common/SignIn.aspx@loginDone=1).

I'm really new to dealing with web from Python so I have no idea what to do. As I understand (although I'm not sure) we need to create a certificate that contains the username and the password. I got the content of the page as follows:

```
r = requests.get(url,verify=False)
```

But I don't understand how to connect. Furthermore, how to keep the session alive so I could enter another page on the website and it won't ask for the username and password again?

**EDIT**: from previous thread I learn that I need to do something like:

```
import requests

LOGIN = 'https://www.hackthis.co.uk/index.php?login'
PROTECTED_PAGE = 'https://www.hackthis.co.uk/news'
payload = {
    'username': 'VALIDUSERNAME',
    'password': 'VALIDPASSWORD'
}

with requests.session() as s:
    s.post(LOGIN, data=payload)
    response = s.get(PROTECTED_PAGE)
    print(response.text)
```

So i did:

```
payload = {
    'TapuzLogin1$ctl01$UserName': 'USER',
    'TapuzLogin1$ctl01$Password': 'PASS'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
  p = s.post("https://www.tapuz.co.il/Common/SignInPage.aspx", verify=False,data=payload)
  print(p.text)
```

But it doesn't connect. Should the username field be `TapuzLogin1$ctl01$UserName` and the password field `TapuzLogin1$ctl01$Password`? Also, Should I press connect afterwards or that should to the trict?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/13827087/1073696 help at all?

Comment: Look at sessions in the requests library.

Comment: Certificates have nothing to do with usernames and passwords.

Comment: The purpose of a certificate is to ensure that the remote hostname you're accessing is legitimate, i.e. you're trying to access `www.apple.com` and you want to be sure that domain name hasn't been hijacked by the Russians.  Usernames and passwords are different -- they prove **your** identity.

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [web scraping dynamic content with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17608572/web-scraping-dynamic-content-with-python)