# Need examples of how to use djangorestframework-api-key

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, api-key

So I am trying to get comfortable using api-keys and this is a package I found and it seems promising. I added the

```
from rest_framework_api_key.permissions import HasAPIKey
permission_classes = [HasAPIKey]
```

Also in settings changed the custom header with

```
API_KEY_CUSTOM_HEADER = "HTTP_API_KEY"
```

and looked at the documentation, but no matter what I pass in as an argument in my url it seems to not work. I pass in `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/questions/API-KEY:********/` with my prefix key and it doesn't work. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

The key is suppose to be passed via request header, NOT the url.

Here is the documentation: https://florimondmanca.github.io/djangorestframework-api-key/guide/#making-authorized-requests

Comment: oh gotcha now, dumb question. How exactly would I do that? like where would I put the argument?

Comment: To be clear, you wouldn't do this in a browser. The key is suppose to be passed as part of the header in your request. Something like this:
`https://stackoverflow.com/a/13827087/152653`