# JWT not getting authorised?

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests, jwt

I'm using the python requests module to try create a programme based on the [Brawl Stars API](https://developer.brawlstars.com). In order to authorise a request, there are 2 requirments: a JSON web token, and for the IP the request is coming from to be on a white list. Despite trying all the solutions i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825278/python-request-with-authentication-access-token) all of them return 'Error 403'. I've definitely white listed the correct IP, and have copied and pasted the entire, raw key from my account page. If anyone has any light to share it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you read the API [documentation](https://developer.brawlstars.com/#/documentation)? I can't view it for some reason. The request might need a customized payload to work

Comment: The Documentation only shows how to create requests, not use the web tokens unfortunately.

Comment: Can you update your question with the exact error message ?