# How to get the cookies from an HTTP request using FastAPI?

Tags: python, http, cookies, fastapi, starlette

Is it possible to get the cookies when someone hits the API? I need to read the cookies for each request.

```
@app.get("/")
async def root(text: str, sessionKey: str = Header(None)):
    print(sessionKey)
    return {"message": text+" returned"}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=5001 ,reload=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in the same way you are accessing the headers in your example (see [docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cookie-params)):

```py
from fastapi import Cookie

@app.get("/")
async def root(text: str, sessionKey: str = Header(None), cookie_param: int | None = Cookie(None)):
    print(cookie_param)
    return {"message": f"{text} returned"}
```

Answer (score 9):

### Option 1

Use the `Request` object to get the cookie you wish, as described in [Starlette documentation](https://www.starlette.io/requests/#cookies).

```py
from fastapi import Request

@app.get('/')
async def root(request: Request):
    return request.cookies.get('sessionKey')
```

### Option 2

Use the `Cookie` parameter, as described in [FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cookie-params/). On a side note, the example below defines the cookie parameter as *optional*, using the type `Union[str, None]`; however, there are other ways doing that as well (e.g., `str | None` in Python 3.10+)—have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73261442/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72289969/17865804) for more details.

```py
from fastapi import Cookie
from typing import Union

@app.get('/')
async def root(sessionKey: Union[str, None] = Cookie(None)):
    return sessionKey
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the variable name 'sessionkey' in option 2 must be equal to the cookie key name.