# How to send Authorization Header through Swagger UI using FastAPI?

Tags: python, reactjs, swagger, swagger-ui, fastapi

In the frontend, I have the following JS function:

```
export const uploadFormData = async (
    token: string,
    email: string,
    formInfo: Array<Object>,
): Promise<any> => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('email', email);
    formData.append('form_info', JSON.stringify({ formInfo }));
    return fetch(
        `${process.env.ENDPOINT}/upload_form_data/`,
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Token ${token}`,
            },
            body: formData,
        },
    ).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.body?.getReader());
        if (response.status === 404) {
            throw Error('Url not found');
        }
        if (response.status === 422) {
            throw Error('Wrong request format');
        }
        if (response.status !== 200) {
            throw Error('Something went wrong with uploading the form data.');
        }
        const data = response.json();
        return {
            succes: true,
            data,
        };
    }).catch((error) => Promise.reject(error));
};
```

which sends a `POST` request to the following endpoint in the FastAPI backend:

```
@app.post("/api/queue/upload_form_data/")
async def upload_form_data(
    email: str = Body(...),  
    form_info: str = Body(...), 
    authorization: str = Header(...),
    
):
    return 'form data processing'
```

However, it keeps throwing the following errors:

1. In the frontend:

   ```
   POST http://localhost:8000/api/queue/upload_form_data/ 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
   Uncaught (in promise) Error: Wrong request format
   ```
2. In the backend:

   ```
   POST /api/queue/upload_form_data/ HTTP/1.1" 400 Bad Request
   ```
3. In Swagger UI (response body):

   ```
   {
     "detail": [
       {
         "loc": [
           "header",
           "authorization"
         ],
         "msg": "field required",
         "type": "value_error.missing"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```

What is wrong with the request that is causing these errors?

Comment: The body of the 422 error will tell you exactly what value is missing and why the request is failing; look in your browser's development tools under Network to see the actual request being sent to the server (and the response with the body).

Answer (score 10):

In Swagger/OpenAPI specification, `Authorization` is a reserved header—along with `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers as well—for Swagger's built-in [authentication/authorization](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/) functionality (see [Swagger documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#header-parameters)). Hence, they are **not allowed** to be defined.

If you are using Swagger, you can't have an `Authorization` header parameter defined in your endpoint and expect it to work, as it would be ignored when submitting the request through Swagger UI, and you would receive a `422 Unprocessable Entity` error with a body message saying that the `authorization` header is miising (just like the error posted in your question).

### Solutions

##### Solution 1

If you **don't** need Swagger UI for testing your application, you can leave it as is and keep using JavaScript [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), passing the `Authorization` in the headers. For example:

```py
from fastapi import Header

@app.post('/')
def main(authorization: str = Header(...)):
    return authorization
```

Also, note that you don't really have to define any `Header` parameters in your endpoint, as you can always access them directly through the `Request` object, for instance:

```py
from fastapi import Request

@app.post('/')
def main(request: Request):
    authorization = request.headers.get('Authorzation')
    return authorization
```

##### Solution 2

If you do need this to work with Swagger UI as well, one solution would be to use FastAPI's [`HTTPBearer`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/e13df8ee79d11ad8e338026d99b1dcdcb2261c9f/fastapi/security/http.py#L100), which would allow you to click on the `Authorize` button at the top right hand corner of your screen in Swagger UI autodocs (at `/docs`), where you can type your API key in the `Value` field. This will set the `Authorization` header in the request headers. Example:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from fastapi.security import HTTPBearer

app = FastAPI()
security = HTTPBearer()

@app.get('/')
def main(authorization: str = Depends(security)):
    return authorization.credentials
```

Alternatively, you could use [`APIKeyHeader`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/e13df8ee79d11ad8e338026d99b1dcdcb2261c9f/fastapi/security/api_key.py#L41) with the desired `name` for the header (in your case, that is, `Authorization`), which would also allow you to click on the `Authorize` button in Swagger UI, in order to set the header value.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Security
from fastapi.security.api_key import APIKeyHeader

app = FastAPI()
api_key_header = APIKeyHeader(name='Authorization')

@app.get('/')
def main(api_key: str = Security(api_key_header)):
    return api_key
```

##### Solution 3

Another solution would be to rename the `authorization` `Header` parameter to something else, e.g., `token`, and define this parameter as `Optional` in your API endpoint. Then, inside your endpoint, check if the API key is in either the `token` or `request.headers.get('Authorization')` parameter—if both return `None`, then this means that no token was provided. Example:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Header
from typing import Optional

app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/')
def main(request: Request, token: Optional[str] = Header(None)):
    authorization = request.headers.get('Authorization')
    return token if token else authorization
```