# Use Authorize button in fastapi swagger UI to send generated token to provide access

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, swagger, fastapi

Steps I am following:

1. `/send_otp` - Send otp to given number
2. `/token` - generate access token if the provide number and otp are correct
3. Authorize button - Need to provide the token to give access *#Need help here*
4. `/show_results` - requires authorization to show results

I am using `oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="/token")` for authorization. The Authorize button is asking to enter username, password, client id and client secret.

How to test from swagger UI? I can use postman with Bearer token, but is it possible to use swagger UI for testing this? How to utilize the Authorize button to provide access to `/show_results` API?

**/token:** route look like

```
@app.post("/token")
def generate_token(phone_number: str, otp: str):
    ...

    # Return OAuth2 token
    return {"access_token": encoded_jwt, "token_type": "bearer"}
```

**/Show_results:** route looks like

```
@app.get("/show_results")
def show_results(token: Optional[str] = Depends(oauth2_scheme)):
    ...
```

[image]

**Authorize button view:**

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send Authorization Header through Swagger UI using FastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74085996/how-to-send-authorization-header-through-swagger-ui-using-fastapi)

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74268404/17865804) helpful as well.

Comment: @Chris, from this suggested [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74088523/11844406), you mean to use `APIKeyHeader` instead of `OAuth2PasswordBearer`?

Comment: @Chris I want to user `OAuth2` authentication, as I read that it is mostly used when there is subscription type authentication requirement, which is why I am using `OAuth2`. It is even fine for me, If I was able to enter phone number and otp using `Authorize` button, which is hitting `/token` url, which will also help in authorize I assume?