# How get token from HTTPBasic form in fastapi

Tags: fastapi, bearer-token

It is my first fastapi app so it might be a very beginner question but several days googling did not return any result.
We are developing a set of APIs using fastapi(0.103.1) and we registered our webapp in a single tenant Azure Active Directory.
In our environment we decided to use Azure ID Token for authentication(Maybe not the best option but after a month of googling/reading and asking questions on stackoverflow, I couldn't come up with a better solution). Putting all security and structure concerns aside, my goal is:

a)the end user could call the API using curl and an id token as bearer token

b)the user could enter username/password on swagger and I internally generate the token

It seems that HTTPBearer would take care of requirement and HTTPBasic would be enough for requirement b but I can't figure out how to accomplish both. There are some materials on net about customizing authentications and inherit from basesecurity class but none of them had details. I tried to write a class using googling results but with my basic knowledge of fastapi, it seems impossible. I would appreciate if somebody could help me understand how I can write such a code or point me to material that help me to do that.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74268404/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: Related answers include [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74088523/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73137093/17865804)

Comment: @Chris, thank you putting time and finding those posts. After going through those questions and answers, they don't seem to be solution that I am looking for at least based on my understanding. I will update my question so it will be more clear.