# FastAPI how to add Authorization header to next requests

Tags: python, authentication, oauth-2.0, fastapi

Been working on an API's authentication and I'm stuck in something kind of simple (I hope). I have a `login` endpoint:

```
@router.get("/login")
def login(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("auth/login.html", {"request": request})


@router.post("/login")
def login(
    request: Request,
    username: str = Form(...),
    password: str = Form(...),

):
    errors = []
    user_db = pd.read_excel('users.xlsx')
    user = authenticate_user(user_db=user_db, username=username, password=password)

    access_token = create_access_token(data={"sub": username})

    response.set_cookie(
        key="access_token", value=f"Bearer {access_token}", httponly=True
    )
    response.headers['Authorization'] = f"Bearer {access_token}"
    return response
```

This works and produces a token, but then I have another endpoint that requires authentication, but it doesn't get the "Authorization" header when I enter, which makes authentication fail:

```
@router.get("/register")
def register(request: Request,
             access_token: Annotated[Union[str, None], Cookie()] = None
             ):
    # print(access_token)
    #print(request.headers['Authorization'])
    return templates.TemplateResponse("auth/register.html", {"request": request})


@router.post("/register")
def register(
    request: Request,
    current_user: Annotated[User, Depends(get_current_active_user)], # This here fails
    username: str = Form(...),
    password: str = Form(...),
    password_confirm: str = Form(...),


):

    print(current_user)

    try:
        user = UserCreate(username=username, password=password, password_confirm=password_confirm,
                          superuser = False)
        if current_user.superuser:
            message = crear_usuario(user=user)
            return JSONResponse(content={'message': message})
        else:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
                detail="User should be a superuser",
                headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
            )
    except ValidationError as e:
        errors_list = json.loads(e.json())
        for item in errors_list:
            errors.append(item.get("loc")[0] + ": " + item.get("msg"))
        return templates.TemplateResponse(
            "auth/register.html", {"request": request, "errors": errors}
        )
```

I managed to send the token programmatically adding the token to the headers in Python, but I need this to work for a regular user. What does the "Authorize" button in Swagger's UI differently that then lets me send the Authorization header with my requests?
[image]

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74088523/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74268404/17865804) helpful.

Comment: I'll take my time to try to parse these responses, thanks @Chris

Comment: @Chris, So, I'm a bit troubled with dependencies. I can access my token through cookies like answer 2 suggests, but because my /register post endpoint depends on `get_current_active _user`, which depends on `get_current_user` , which has the token as a parameter, I'm not sure how to proceed to pass the token. Do you have any ideas? thanks a lot

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74011067/17865804) answer your question? Related answers can also be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74019824/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74105859/17865804)

Comment: I just noticed it and deleted it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your `login` endpoint you should return token not in `headers`, but in `body` and you don't need to set cookies since you use `Bearer` authentication scheme:

```
@router.post("/login")
def login(
    request: Request,
    username: str = Form(...),
    password: str = Form(...),

):
    errors = []
    user_db = pd.read_excel('users.xlsx')
    user = authenticate_user(user_db=user_db, username=username, password=password)

    access_token = create_access_token(data={"sub": username})

    return {"access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer"}
```

And, to make Swagger's green `Authorize` button work, you should create the instance of `OAuth2PasswordBearer` class:

```
oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="login")
```

Then use this `oauth2_scheme` as a dependency to get a token in your `get_current_user`:

```
async def get_current_user(token: Annotated[str, Depends(oauth2_scheme)]):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to do it this way:

```
@router.post("/register")
def register(
    request: Request,

    username: str = Form(...),
    password: str = Form(...),
    password_confirm: str = Form(...),
    superuser: bool = Form(False),
    access_token: Annotated[Union[str, None], Cookie()] = None


):

    token = access_token

    _, token = get_authorization_scheme_param(token)
    current_user = get_current_user(token)

    errors = []
    try:
        user = UserCreate(username=username, password=password, password_confirm=password_confirm,
                          superuser=superuser)
        if current_user.superuser:
            message = crear_usuario(user=user)
            return JSONResponse(content={'message': message})
        else:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
                detail="Solo un superusuario puede crear usuarios",
                headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
            )
    except ValidationError as e:
        errors_list = json.loads(e.json())
        for item in errors_list:
            errors.append(item.get("loc")[0] + ": " + item.get("msg"))
        return templates.TemplateResponse(
            "auth/register.html", {"request": request, "errors": errors}
        )
```

It isn't compatible with Swagger's UI, but I'll have to pay that cost