# How to authorize OpenAPI/Swagger UI page in FastAPI?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, fastapi, swagger-ui, openapi

I'm building a FastAPI application with OAuth2 and JWT authentication. I've got two endpoints that create the JWT token. The first is hidden from the OpenAPI page but is used by the page `Authorize` button. The second does the same functionality but is available to the users as an API endpoint.

If the user uses the page `Authorize` button and successfully gets authenticated, the rest of the API endpoints on the OpenAPI page become accessible.

If the user uses the API `get_token` endpoint only, they get a valid JWT token, which can be used with the protected API's, but the OpenAPI page isn't authenticated.

How can I use the token returned by the public `get_token` API endpoint to authenticate the OpenAPI page as if the user went through OpenAPI provided `Authorize` functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `Authorize` button, the `Authorization` header with the token in it is automatically sent in every subsequent request you make to the FastAPI backend, and hence, the user gets authenticated.

Using your `get_token` endpoint, users will obtain the token as a response, and have to manually place it in the headers for every request they make. As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74088523/17865804), as `Authorization` is a reserved header in Swagger UI/OpenAPI specification, you either have to define a `Header` parameter in your endpoints with a different name, e.g., `token`, where users will place the `token` value (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74088523/17865804) as well), or use the `Authorize` button, which will automatically add it for every request to any endpoint of your server.

Another option would be to create an `httponly` cookie (using the [`Set-Cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) header) with the token inside once the user calls the `get_token` endpoint, and [return the cookie with the `Response` object](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-cookies/), as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74060795/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73137093/17865804). The browser will store the cookie sent by the server and will send it back with every request made to the server inside a [`Cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) HTTP header (read more about cookies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73599289/17865804)). Inside the endpoint, you can then retrieve the token using the [`Request` object](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/using-request-directly/#details-about-the-request-object) directly, for example, `request.cookies.get('token')`, or by defining a [cookie parameter](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cookie-params/) for it.

Comment: Thanks Chris, this all makes sense. I'll need to dig into this to balance the use case between the OpenAPI page, or users using something like PostMan, where they would have to add the Bearer token to the Authorization header.