# FastAPI Docs security example based login

Tags: authentication, security, oauth-2.0, jwt, fastapi

I managed to build a login system with FastAPI using the online documentation security section example. It's more or less the same except you have to get user from MySql.
I have two problems.
I can only authorize thru FastAPI Docs top right green Authorize button.

API Login function kind of works a valid jwt but...

also gives an error ( handled by API I guess )

```bsh
(trapped) error reading bcrypt version
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/passlib/handlers/bcrypt.py", line 620, in \_load_backend_mixin
version = \_bcrypt.__about__.__version__
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'bcrypt' has no attribute '__about__'
INFO:     127.0.0.1:49518 - "POST /login/token HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

And then, when I use this function which depends on jwt...

```py
@router.get("/users/me/", response_model=schemas.User)
async def read_users_me(
current_user: Annotated\[schemas.User, Depends(get_current_active_user)\]
):
return current_user
```

I get this response from server..

```json
{
"detail": "Not authenticated"
}
```

However, if I login thru FastAPI/Swagger Docs Authorize then everything works.
I checked my token url and seems fine.
Any ideas?

I tried to create a login end point from my FastAPI end like explained in this [example](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/)
However, I could not get it fully working..

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74268404/17865804). You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963905/17865804) helpful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you login through Swagger login button, Swagger will store received token and attach it to every request (in headers).

But if you login by just using your endpoint (even if you do it through Swagger docs) Swagger will not store your token and attach it to every request. Swagger will just send login request, receive the response and show you this response.

You can also check it with 'fetch'. Open some url of your API in browser, open developer instruments, console.
Call login endpoint and receive token (check login url, username and password)

```
 fetch(
 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/login',
 {
     method: 'POST',
     credentials: "include",
     headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
     body: "username=EMAIL&password=PWD"
 }
 ).then(resp => resp.text()).then(console.log)
```

Then try using protected endpoint and send token in headers (substitude TOKEN_RECEIVED_IN_PREVIOUS_STEP with your token)

```
 fetch(
 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/me',
 {
     method: 'GET',
     credentials: "include",
     headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer TOKEN_RECEIVED_IN_PREVIOUS_STEP' }
 }
 ).then(resp => resp.text()).then(console.log)
```

Comment: So, I need to implement a way to store the token and attach it to allowed API ends?
But it looks like FastAPI security example suggested otherwise...
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/simple-oauth2/
Or.. did I get it wrong?
This is gonna be consumed by an react native app so I need to implement a login function for to read parts of API

Comment: In your front-end application, you must implement logic that will call the login endpoint, save the token, and send this token in headers with each subsequent request. Perhaps some frameworks can do this out of the box, since you use a standard authorization scheme.

Comment: I couldn't find anything in FastAPI documentation that differs from how your code works.

Comment: Yes... some of the implementations you mentioned, are built-in FastAPI I guess. I could not find anything related to sending jwts with each header either. So, the problem I mentioned above is still not resolved I guess.

Comment: What is the problem? Do you want Swagger to send a token in headers at every request, even if you login through an endpoint call (and not through a special Swagger login button)?

Comment: I want to be able to login from api end and inject dependency for this token  to allow different api ends for different user types.
But, that is the final goal. Right now, I want to be able to login from api end and use certain api ends

Comment: As I understand you have already done it. You can login with green login button in Swagger docs and then you can use protected endpoints. If it works then it means that you have implemented it correctly.

Comment: Using green login button is the right way how to check the authentication system in your API. You can also check it by sending requests with `fetch` or `curl` (I added the example in my answer)